# Detect when user tapped Don't Allow when making changes to photo library

Tags: ios, phasset, phphotolibrary

When you want to make a change to a `PHAsset`, you wrap it up in a `performChanges` block. You get a success `Bool` and an error `NSError` in the completion block. Now I would like to show an alert to the user in the case the request failed. This does the trick:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: asset)
    request.creationDate = date
}, completionHandler: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if let error = error {
            //present alert
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is when the user taps Don't Allow it also presents the alert. I don't want to do that, the user intentionally canceled it so there's no need to inform them it failed. But how can I detect that's what has occurred? The error `userInfo` is `nil`, it doesn't seem it provides any useful info to detect that case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try looking at the error's code. There is probably a specific code used to indicate the user denied access.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, the `error.code` is `-1`, which appears to be a generic error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible by checking if the `error` is a `PHPhotosError` and if so checking its `code` to see if it's `.userCancelled`.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: asset)
    request.creationDate = date
}) { success, error in
    guard let error = error else { return }
    guard (error as? PHPhotosError)?.code != .userCancelled else { return }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //present alert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {

```
 NSLog(@"%ld",(long)status);

switch (status) {

    case PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:

        // code for display photos


          NSLog(@"ffefwfwfwef");

    case PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted:



        break;
    case PHAuthorizationStatusDenied:

       //code for Dont Allow code

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}];

Comment: PHAuthorizationStatus is different. Authorization status is not related to the approval of photo content editing.